# If $X$ and $Y$ are uniform random variables, and $Z = \max(X,Y)$, then what is the expected value of $Z$?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expectation

I'm kind of new here so plz tell me how I can make my questions clearer?

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two i.i.d $U[0,2]$ random variables and $Z = \max(X,Y)$. What is the expected value of $Z$?

The answer is $\frac{4}{3}$ but I absolutely have zero clue about how to start to even get there, can anyone please help a poor lost soul?

Comment: where are you stuck? What has you tried?

Comment: For future posts, please try to use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

A good way to handle problems you are a bit confused on is to go back to the cumulative distribution functions.  In this case, the CDF for a uniform random variate on $[0,2]$ is simply $P(X \leq x) = \frac{x}{2}$ for $0\leq x \leq 2$  (and zero for $x<0$ and one for $x>2$).

Now we would llike to find the CDF for $\max(X,Y)$. 
So, what is the probability that said maximum is less than some value $m$?
Well, $X$ and $Y$ are independent, so

$$P(X\leq m \wedge Y \leq m) = P (X\leq m ) \cdot P (Y\leq m )
\\ P(\max(X,Y) \leq m) = (\frac12 m)( \frac12 m)=  \frac{m^2}{4}
$$
So we have a random variate $M$ whose CDF is $\frac14 m^2$; its probability density function is the derivative of the CDF, so 
$$f(m) = \frac{m}{2}$$
Finally, the expected value of $M$ is 
$$
\int_0^2 m\,f(m)\,dm = \int_0^2 \frac{m^2}{2}\,dm = \frac{2^3}{6} = \frac43
$$

Comment: Thank you sooo much this was very clear and I was able to follow along while doing my calculations

Comment: @Max It took me some ten seconds to understand the joke... I know a chinese colleague dual to you.